# Userform not initializating despite proper header

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm attempting to write a new UserForm that loads controls upon initialization.

For whatever reason the test module I've written does not load anything within the UserForm on runtime although the UserForm itself does appear.

Module code:

```
Sub test()

Dim check As New UserForm1

Load check
check.Show

End Sub
```

UserForm code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim submit As MSForms.CommandButton
Set submit = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "Submit")

With submit
    .Caption = "Submit"
End With

End Sub
```

No button appears when I run the module, however, when I run the UserForm code directly it initializes properly. Any advice?

Comment: What's your first bit of code supposed to be doing? Do you have a Userform1 already created?

Comment: FWIW `Load check` is superfluous/no-op.

Comment: @PeicongChen `MSForms` is the name of the type library that defines the `CommandButton` class.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon New stuff to learn, Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @SJR Sorry for being so late about this, but the first bit of code is how a macro is actually executed within the Excel workbook. The second bit is supposed to be what occurs when a UserForm is initialized, but initialization only begins when a UserForm is created and shown in the first bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Set submit = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "Submit")
> ```

That *is* adding the button... just not on the `check` instance.

See [UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/); by referencing `UserForm1` in the `UserForm1` module, you've referred to that form's *default instance*, which may or may not be the instance that's currently being initialized.

This should fix it:

```
Set submit = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "Submit")
```

A `UserForm` module is a class, with a visual designer component and a `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute value set to `True`. The *predeclared* instance is the result of that hidden `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute value, and as per language specifications its name matches the name of the class itself, i.e. `UserForm1`. By using `Me` as a qualifier instead of `UserForm1`, you refer to *whatever instance is currently running*, as opposed to *the class' default instance*.

Avoid referring to the default instance in a form's code-behind.